# Database Table 'PACIENTE' does not exist

Tags: java, database, desktop-application, derby

I'm trying to make a java desktop database application, using the derby embedded database, I'm having some issues that I can't quite fix, and I've searched (a lot) for the answers, found some, but they couldn't solve my problem, so I decided to make a question myself. I made the database on netbeans, jut like a whole bunch of tutorials teach, downloaded the derby.jar and added to the library on the project, but then when I try to insert some data in the database's table that I created is says that the table doesn't exist. 
I'm pretty sure i'm missing something really stupid, but I can't figure it out by myself, so any help will be very much appreciate. I'm new to all this java database development, I had only created local databases on c#

PS: The schema is the 'APP' one, I tried using "INSERT INTO APP.PACIENTE (ID, NOME) VALUES (1, 'victor')" but that didn't work either

```
    public class BancoDados {

private static String url = "jdbc:derby:MeuBancoDados;create=true";
private static String driver = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
static Connection conn;
static Statement sta;


public static void insert() throws SQLException, ClassNotFoundException, InstantiationException, IllegalAccessException {

    conn = null;
    sta = null;
     try {

        Class.forName(driver);
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        sta = conn.createStatement();
        sta.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO PACIENTE (ID, NOME) VALUES (1, 'victor')");

        sta.close();
        conn.close();

        System.out.println("Inserido com sucesso!");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Exception: " + e.getMessage());

    }
}
}
```

I get This error:

```
    Exception in thread "main" ERROR 42X05: Table 'PACIENTE' does not exist.
at org.apache.derby.iapi.error.StandardException.newException(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.DMLModStatementNode.verifyTargetTable(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.compile.InsertNode.bind(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepMinion(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.GenericStatement.prepare(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.sql.conn.GenericLanguageConnectionContext.prepareInternalStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.execute(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.derby.impl.jdbc.EmbedStatement.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
at projcad.BancoDados.insert(BancoDados.java:31)
at projcad.projcad.main(projcad.java:8)
```

Java Result: 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Table 'PACIENTE' does not exist.

This is because in database you have not created the `PACIENTE` table.

Create it.

Comment: Ok, that is my problem, I've already created the table on the database explorer, that's not the way to do it?